# How to upload a Firefox OS app on Android

Tags: android, firefox-os

I'm developing an app for Firefox OS and I would like to test it on my Android phone. Is it possible? I only found articles about installing apps from the Firefox Marketplace.

I could connect my Android device to the WebIDE, but it only makes possible to debug web pages on Firefox for Android, and does not work for uploading apps through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Testing Your Native Android App](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/06/testing-your-native-android-app/) blog post describes using the [mozilla-apk-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mozilla-apk-cli) to do this.

(Eventually that documentation should migrate to the [How can I test/debug APKs?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Open_web_apps_for_android#How_can_I_test.2Fdebug_APKs.3F) section of the [Open web apps for Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Open_web_apps_for_android) page.)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your app from any computer with a web server. You just need a single html file and a "mini" manifest, then you access that page from you phone (using firefox for android, of course) and you will be able to install the app as you would install it from the marketplace.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Marketplace/Options/Self_publishing)